# C++ library for the 3-dimensional assignment problem

Tags: library, c++, programming

The 3-dimensional assignment problem is an extension of the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Given 3 groups of n people we want to split them into n triplets such that each possible triplet has a non-negative cost and is made from 1 person from the first group one from the second group and one from the third in a way that the total cost of the n triplets is minimized.

This problem is a NP-complete problem however a simple google search shows there exist many polynomial time constant approximation algorithms for that problem but I couldn't find any implemented library that does that.

Is there any open source c++ (or even other language) library that solves this problem in polynomial time and gives a constant approximation for the optimal solution?

Comment: You might be interested in https://hackernoon.com/the-assignment-problem-calculating-the-minimum-matrix-sum-python-1bba7d15252d

Comment: @SteveBarnes No, this is a regular assignment problem, not 3d.

Comment: Just add a dimension!

Comment: @SteveBarnes How? [as explained here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X01003432) this is a NP-hard problem, you can't just add a dimension.